# Is there a way to dynamically re-initialize JSColor without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jscolor

I'm currently working on a project that uses only HTML, CSS, and Javascript with no additional frameworks like jQuery. I'm also using Webpack / Babel.

I need to be able to dynamically add instances of the JSColor color picker. I'm currently using a CDN link in the index page to download the library, but if there's a way to properly load it into my entry file I'd be happy to put it in the project directory instead.

I've researched the problem, and it seems like the common solution is to include `jscolor.init()` at the end of the code. However, with a CDN link and some HTML sitting in the index file, I'm unsure of how to access the jsColor object.

```
  const colorPicker = document.createElement('button');

  colorPicker.classList.add(`jscolor`);
  colorPicker.classList.add(`{value:'${conditionalHash[currentType].color}'}`);

  currentOption.append(colorPicker);
```

Edit: I have tried downloading the library and including it in my project directory as well. I imported it into my entry file and tried to instantiate it with the following code:

```
import JSColor from "./assets/jscolor";

const jscolorpicker = new JSColor;
console.log(jscolorpicker);
```

However, I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: _jscolor2.default is not a constructor

Edit #2: Here's my webpack file, by request.

```
module.exports = {


entry: "./entry.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders:[{
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css?sourceMap'
    }, {
      test: /\.js?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: "babel-loader",
      presets: "es2015"
    }, {
      test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff(2)?)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?/,
      loader: 'url'
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: `import ... from...` is not supported by any browsers at present. You need to manually do `<script src="jscolor.js"></script>`.

Comment: @Dai, I'm using Webpack.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could show your `webpack.config.js` and how you build this.

Comment: @mfirry, I uploaded my webpack config. I don't know what you mean as far as "how I built this." The code above is wrapped in a function that is executed after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I figure you just `webpack` to produce your bundle then

Comment: Yes. I can access JSColor through either a CDN link in the head of my index file, or (I think, but it's not working yet) by adding the jscolor.js file into my project directory and importing it into the entry file.

Comment: `colorPicker.classList.add(\`{value:'${conditionalHash[currentType].color}'}\`);` just is not going to work. That will render like `<button class="jscolor {value:'abcdef'}"></button>`, assuming `${conditionalHash[currentType].color}` evaluates to "abcdef". That's not a valid class name.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, Have you read jscolor's documentation? It can read from classes...

Comment: I don't need to read the documentation to know that's an invalid CSS class name. Just because the library can read it doesn't make it valid. It just means the library is encouraging the use of invalid CSS.

Comment: The classnames for jscolor aren't meant to be interacted with via CSS, I think.

Comment: For what it's worth, the jscolor configuration can also be added as a `data-jscolor` attribute, rather than in the class.